# Android WebView, setRotationX() / setRotationY() doesn't work

Tags: android, webview, rotation

I was trying to rotate WebView with setRotationX() / setRotationY() methods but if they are used, web page contents get completely messed up.

Are these rotation methods applicable to WebViews?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried using software and hardware layers (LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE / HARDWARE) - either web page content is rendered incorrectly, or UI gets quite slow especially if there are many WebViews. So currently, best solution is to use OpenGL for 3D effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question, these are the solutions:

- use only simplest web pages and built-in 3D rotation methods (setRotationX()/Y()) will work
- 'take screenshot' of a WebView and use it as a texture in OpenGL to do 3D transformations
- wait until built-in 3D methods are fixed for WebView's

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use setRequestedOrientation ?

or if you only want to rotate the webview content, why don't you do this directly in your webview content, using javascript ?

Comment: Hi Jule, I'm trying to rotate the whole WebView around X or Y axis; this has the effect of 3D. setRequestedOrientation, on the other hand, "rotates" around the Z axis.